# React Hooks with addEventListener from Socketio

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import socketiIO from 'socket.io-client';

function App() {
    
  const endpoint = "http://X.X.X.X:5000/";
  const socket = socketiIO(endpoint);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("no message");

  function firstrun(){
    socket.on("connect", ()=>{
      socket.emit("message", {"data":"ahoi"});
    });
    socket.addEventListener("my response", (data)=>{
      console.log(data)
      //setMessage(data["data"]);
    });
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    firstrun();
  },[]);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {message}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Backend.py

```
import time
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "secret!"
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins = "*")

def test_message_2(message):
    emit("my response",
        {"data": message})

@socketio.on("message")
def test_message(message):
    print(message)
    for idx in range(int(1e3)):
        time.sleep(1)
        test_message_2(idx)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, port = 5000)
```

Here is an excerpt from my code where the server is pulsing the client side with continuous data, at a given interval. If I `console.log(data)` the data in shown in the console log of the browser, but if I try to `setMessage(data["data"])`(uncomment it) the stream halts after 4 iterations? Am I misusing react hooks or is it something else?

Comment: What do u mean by halt? The event "my response" is not triggered anymore?

Comment: Is the api you are using correct? shall u use socket.on instead of socket.addEventListener?

Comment: Yes, If I comment out the line the EventListener doesn't trigger after 3 iterations.

Comment: useEffect(()=>{
    socket.on("my response", (data)=>{
      setMessage(data["data"]);
    });
  },[message]);
// This doesn't work either

Comment: Can u also share ur server side code

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-store-a-function-with-the-usestate-hook-in-react-8a88dd4eede1 here is the answer, I was using hooks wrong